# Get user records from Sentry in desc order

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, cartalyst-sentry

I want to get user records from Laravel Sentry package.

This code return user records from DB:

```
$customer = Sentry::findGroupByName('Users');
$customer = Sentry::findAllUsersInGroup($customer);
return View::make('admin.store.customer')->with('customer', $customer);
```

How to sort user records in descending order?

Answer (score 0):

you can try :

```
Sentry::findAllUsersInGroup($customer)->count();
```

to get count, and after adding a loop for order them.